# css last-child not working when adding divs of different classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="SomeContainer">
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyOtherClass"></div>
</div>
```

And I use the following CSS

```
.MyClass{...}
.MyClass:last-child{box-shadow:0px 5px 10px black;}
```

I wrongly assumed that `last-child` operated on the last child of a certain class but it actually operates on the last-child of the container if it's of the same class.

Is there some convenient way around? I know I could add a wrapper around the `MyClass` div and add the CSS for the shadow to the wrapper but I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you've already tried using CSS3 selectors then <strike>this is the correct pseudo class to use</strike>

```
.MyClass:last-of-type
```

According to [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo) (at least as I understand it) this should work but it seems it doesn't. At least not in latest Chrome (v23) and Firefox (v17) browser versions.

> **WARNING:** Upper information doesn't work and may be misleading that there's a pure  CSS solution to this problem... Because as of CSS3 there's none. CSS4 on the other hand will have an additional pseudo class `:nth-last-match(n)` that will likely cover this exact scenario. But it's too early to say when not all CSS3 selectors have been implemented by browsers.

### Additional investigation

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anHHU/3) that shows how this pseudo class selector actually works:

1. get all elements that satisfy CSS selector (without pseudo)
2. get their different HTML element types (tags)
3. select all sibling elements of the same type (tag) for each type (tag) group
4. Reduce each type (tag) group to the last element in the group
5. Does this remaining element (of each group) satisfy selector (without pseudo)?
6. If **true** then apply style otherwise don't

This means (as my example also shows) that several sibling elements can satisfy this selector as long as they're of different type.

This seems to work the same way in Chrome and Firefox. And if we carefully read specification it does say

> The `:last-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the **last sibling of its type** in the list of children of its parent element.

If it said that it's the *last sibling that satisfied selector* then my upper solution would work. So lets test my steps.

#### Run steps through using your HTML

1. gets first 3 elements
2. only one type: `div`
3. four element (including the last one)
4. reduce to the last one
5. satisfies? **No**
6. don't set style

#### Other couple of examples in my fiddle

Just to test this pseudo class selector behaviour I added two additional examples. Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- First -->
<div class="SomeContainer">
    <div class="MyClass">Content</div>
    <div class="MyClass">Content</div> 
    <p class="MyClass">Content</p>
    <p class="MyClass">Content</p>
</div>

<!-- Second -->
<div class="SomeContainer">
    <div class="MyClass">Content</div>
    <div class="MyClass">Content</div>
    <div class="MyClass">Content</div>
    <p class="MyOtherClass">Content</p>
</div>
```

In the first one two elements satisfy selector (last `div` and last `p`).
In the second one one element satisfies selector (last `div`)

### Outcome

Having HTML that you provided and assuming that there can be an arbitrary number of elements with `.MyClass` there's no way to write a general selector in CSS3 that would actually target the last element with particular CSS class.

The best way is to add additional class to elements that represent the last one with particular class and write a selector to target that.

Comment: That should work but I decided to just add a class that defines my shadow programmatically since I'm also generating the HTML that way; it's a loop that creates divs MyClass and at the end, just add the class that does the shadow. It works fine.

Comment: @frenchie: It should yes at first look. But I've investigated even further and checked spec carefully and it doesn't. I've added explanation how this pseudo class actually works.

Comment: @BoltClock: **You're wrong when you say that my steps are invalid.** Your example still proves that they're correct. I'm not saying that browser renderers actually work as per my steps. No. I just wanted to explain how this selector is applied. In your example when you added additional `div` that element gets added in my step 3 and when group gets reduced in step 4, your added element is the one that's left. And it doesn't satisfy selector (without pseudo) so it's not specially styled. My steps still work.

Comment: @BoltClock: No worries. I'm just thinking if it could be somehow combined with `:not()` to actually get last of its selector but I think it isn't possible either... There should be a selector `:last-of-selector` that would satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Well, in Selectors 4 there is `:nth-last-match(1 of selector)` that matches against siblings (similar to `:nth-last-child(1)` or `:nth-last-of-type(1)`). It looks promising! But the syntax is quite awkward: `:nth-last-match(1 of .MyClass)`.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ok. Then we can maybe also expect pseudo class `:last-match` to have a similar set of related pseudos as we have in CSS3... Even though it's not in CSS4 proposal yet... If not, we'll just use `:nth-last-match(1)`... Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering why they didn't include it. Maybe they thought it wouldn't be worth the time listing it in the spec until it's confirmed people are interested in implementing it.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think that spec implies usage `.MyClass:nth-last-match(1)` and not `:nth-last-match(1 of .MyClass)` as you're saying. It would be easier to understand if they've added an example as with other selectors and since there's no similar pseudo class to this one we can interpret that *of selector* as we want to. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like last-of-type will only help you if you make your last element not the same as the rest, classnames don't seem to be relavant here.  This example does correctly show two red squares, one green, the one blue.

```
.SomeContainer > div, .SomeContainer > span { width: 20px; height: 20px; background: red}
.SomeContainer > div:last-of-type {background: green}
.SomeContainer > span:last-child {box-shadow:0px 5px 10px black; background: blue; display: block}
```

```
<div class="SomeContainer">
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <span class="MyOtherClass"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what OP's after. They want to select the last `div` with class **MyClass** and not the last child...

Comment: Exactly, the "type" in `:last-of-type` refers to "element type", or its tag name. Anything else is irrelevant.